# How can Chrome download files without storage permission on Android?

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-permissions

Recently I removed storage permission on Chrome app on my Android phone and went to a pdf url file and I was able to download it successfully to my Downloads folder using the Download option.
How can they do this?

Comment: It might be possible using the Storage Access Framework, further information: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files